# Continuity of subharmonic functions

Tags: harmonic-functions, potential-theory

I'm learning Perron's method and have a question on the definition of subharmonic functions.

***Definition*** Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded domain. A function u: $\Omega \to [-\infty, +\infty)$ is called subharmonic if it is *upper semicontinuous* and, for every closed disk $B(a,r) \subset \Omega$, we have the inequality
\begin{equation}
u(a) \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 u(a+re^{i\theta})d\theta.
\end{equation}

In different textbooks, for a function $u$ to be subharmonic, someone requires that $u$ is *continuous*.  In the Perron method, I don't see any difference of such two definitions, and each definiton works well to solve the Dirichlet problem.

**My question is**: what's the difference between these two definitions? I mean, is there any situation that we have to define a subharmonic harmonic to be upper semicontinuous?

Comment: Insofar as the defining property of subharmonic functions is the aforementioned integral inequality, neither continuity nor semicontinuity are required at all - we need only for $u$ to be integrable on the circles $\partial \mathbb B(z,r)\subset \Omega$